# Request parameter in jsp

Tags: asp.net, jsp, servlets, request

As you know in asp, we can do

```
Response.Write("page.aspx?id=3");
```

On the other page `Request.QueryString["id"];`

Well, i want to do samething in jsp using servlets through doGet() and do Post() method.
I want to ask how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doGet or doPost you have access to the request object. So, you can do `request.getParameter("id")`

Comment: can i pass multiple parameters at once.....?

like in asp `page.aspx?id=2&c_id=4`

Comment: @user **yes** <!------------------->